# How to replace a full console logs with preceding whitespaces and possible new line from string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace a `console.log('')` construction in a string using regex. Before the console log there can be random number of whitespaces and one or zero new line characters '\n'. I want to delete it together with the console log. Here is my code:

```
const consoleRegex = new RegExp(/\\n?\s+console\.log\(.*\);?/);
let v = "<script>\n  console.log('test');\n</script>"

v = v.replace(consoleRegex, '');
```

The desired result is `<script>\n</script>`. When I test the regex in the tester it works however it does not get replaced.

Thanks

Comment: Try `/\s+console\.log\(.*\);?/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it removes the whitespaces however not the \n

Comment: Yes, but you want to keep one, see https://ideone.com/hCzZXA

Comment: ahh, correct @WiktorStribiżew, thank you! feel free to post an answer

Comment: The `\\n` matches a backslash and an `n` char, but the string contains an actual newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
let v = "<script>\n  console.log('test');\n</script>";
console.log(v.replace(/\s+console\.log\(.*\);?/, ''));
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/hCzZXA)

Output:

```
"<script>\n</script>"
```

*Details*:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `console\.log\(` - a literal `console.log(` text
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `;?` - an optional `;` char.